# Angular ui-grid expandable row template - ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-grid

I have a scenario where in the response from the service has a lot more fields than what I have to display in UI. is there any way i can check on the view for the particular key before attaching to the ng-model property?

for e.g. testData = {active: 'false', code: '1002', ruleInfos: [{id: '12', desc: 'Test Rule', ruleDefinitions:[{fieldName: 'maxWgt', fieldValue: '100lbs'},{fieldName: 'maxWidth', fieldValue: '100ft'}]}]};

i tried this:

div class="col-md-9" ng-repeat="(key, value) in row.entity.subData

trying to print:

{{key}}

{{value}}

it prints out 'active' & 'false'respectively. but, what i want to display is the value for 'code'.

I would want to display only 'code' and ruleInfos to the user. please note that I need to identify the field name (as the rules is going to be dynamic, meaning i might not get the same rule types always) before mapping to the fields i have defined. please suggest a way around it

Comment: You mention ui-grid in the title but instead you are just using ng-repeat!

Comment: Hello @Mike, I am trying to show a different template than a sub-grid upon expansion. Yes, you are right, i may not need a ngRepeat here. I was just trying to see how it prints and what the row.entity.subData holds. My requirement is to attach only certain fields among many available fields and they are in an array form.

Comment: Can you remove the quotes from active: false. Then it will stop being a string. Have you tried to print testData.ruleInfos as a text field just as a test. If that is still a valid object then I presume the inner ng-repeat loop is to print it out. Can you show your code there